# How can I format a datetime using vertica

Tags: vertica

I'm try to formating a field datetime like this "MM-DD-YYYY" but I have a wrong result.

SELECT
   TO_DATE(so_fecha_debito_ach::VARCHAR(11),'MM-DD-YYYY')  as fecha_debito_ach

with this is the same error:

select to_date(so_fecha_debito_ach,'Mon DD YYYY')  as fecha_debito_ach

[Code: 3457, SQL State: 42883]  [Vertica]VJDBC ERROR: Function to_date(timestamp, unknown) does not exist, or permission is denied for to_date(timestamp, unknown)

Answer (score 0):

`TO_DATE()` transforms a string to a date value, while `TO_CHAR()` is to be used to transform a value to a string. That's not only so in Vertica.

Using `TO_CHAR()`, I think you do get what you are looking for:

```
WITH
input(so_fecha_debito_ach) AS (
SELECT DATE '2020-02-29'
)
SELECT
  so_fecha_debito_ach
, TO_CHAR(so_fecha_debito_ach,'DD-MM-YYYY') AS euro_with_dash
, TO_CHAR(so_fecha_debito_ach,'Mon DD YYYY') AS mon_dd_yyyy
FROM input;
-- out  so_fecha_debito_ach | euro_with_dash | mon_dd_yyyy 
-- out ---------------------+----------------+-------------
-- out  2020-02-29          | 29-02-2020     | Feb 29 2020
-- out (1 row)
-- out 
-- out Time: First fetch (1 row): 66.360 ms. All rows formatted: 66.451 ms
```